# extract data from a div that have no class using xpath

Tags: xpath

Code

```
    <div id="content">
        <div class="sample">sample text</div>
        <div class="datebar">
           <span style="float:right">some text1</span>
           <b>some text2</b>
        </div>
     <p>paragraph 1</p>
     <p>paragraph 2</p> 
   </div>
```

I want to get data that in `<p>` tags or you can say that is coming after `<div class="datebar">`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//div[@id="content"]/p/text()
```

Would achieve what you're asking for with your provided sample.

---

**Update**
If you only wanted those `<p>` that came after `<div class="datebar">`. The following should work:

```
//div[@id = 'content']/p[preceding-sibling::div[@class='datebar']]/text()
```

---

**Another Update** - For Kirill

Here's a sample of HTML which has an extra `<p>` before `<div class="datebar">` and xpath expressions tested using python.

Obviously, the solution depends on what the full input HTML is and what the OP wants to extract, neither of which are clear at the moment.

```py
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> doc = etree.HTML("""
... <div id="content">
...   <div class="sample">sample text</div>
...   <p>paragraph 1</p>
...   <div class="datebar">
...     <span style="float:right">some text1</span>
...     <b>some text2</b>
...   </div>
...   <p>paragraph 2</p>
...   <p>paragraph 3</p>
... </div>""")
>>> # My first suggestion
... doc.xpath("//div[@id='content']/p/text()")
['paragraph 1', 'paragraph 2', 'paragraph 3']
>>> # Kirill's solution
... doc.xpath("//div[@id = 'content' and div[@class = 'datebar']]/p/text()")
['paragraph 1', 'paragraph 2', 'paragraph 3']
>>> # My response to Kirill
... doc.xpath("//div[@id = 'content']/p[preceding-sibling::div[@class='datebar']]/text()")
['paragraph 2', 'paragraph 3']
```

Kirill's expression of `//div[@id = 'content' and div[@class = 'datebar']]/p/text()` does not select

> only those `p` which parent `div` has `@id = 'content'` and have preceding `div` with `@class = 'datebar'`

As stated in his comments.

Comment: would it get data from all p tags?

Comment: All `<p>` that are children of `<div id="content">`

Comment: It is getting only first p tag :(

Comment: xpath should return a sequence for this query. Are you sure you're using your xpath supporting library correctly?

Comment: @MattH, Well, "Provided XPath will select only those p which parent div has @id = 'content' and `div` with `@class = 'datebar'` is in the same level as selected `p`". An I right?

Comment: @Kirill. I'm not sure which expression you are talking about now. You've got a massive rep and badges for `xpath`, I can only assume we've been talking cross purposes. I think I've demonstrated everything I've claimed.

Comment: @MattH, +1 for samples and explanations. I think OP must update his question with more detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

```
//div[@id = 'content' and div[@class = 'datebar']]/p/text()
```

Comment: Any reason to expect invalid HTML and therefore the need to differentiate a supposedly unique `id="content"` with an additional term in the predicate?

Comment: @MattH, Provided XPath will select only those `p` which parent `div` has `@id = 'content'` and have preceding `div` with `@class = 'datebar'`.

Comment: the solution you provided doesn't do that. It specifies that the `<div id="content">` must have a child `<div class="datebar">`. To do what you say you'd need: `//div[@id = 'content']/p[preceding-sibling::div[@class='datebar']]/text()`

Comment: @MattH, Provide 2 samples, which have different results using provided XPath and in your comment.